# why $\frac{1}{z}\leqslant\frac{1}{y}+2\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin\frac{1}{x},&x\neq0\\ 0, &x=0 \end{cases}.$$
and $0\leqslant x<y$, $z=\sup\{u\leqslant y|f(u)=f(x)\}$.
Why $\frac{1}{z}\leqslant\frac{1}{y}+2\pi$?.This is the middle step of solving our final exam questions, but I can't understand it.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Thank you,$z\in[x,y)$ be the greatest number for which $f(z)=f(x)$